# How to convert data part of an object into XML using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

First of all, I'm sorry if the question is not clear. I'm trying to create an XML out of an object with its content in it using XStream.

Following is the form of XML I'm trying to achieve:

```
<Tag attr1 = "some_value" attr2 = "some_value"> CONTENT </Tag>
```

I'm having trouble designing the class.

Following is how I have implemented it so far:

```
@XStreamAlias("Tag")
public class Tag {

  @XStreamAsAttribute
  private String attr1;

  @XStreamAsAttribute
  private String attr2;

  private String content;

  public Tag(String content) {

    this.content = content;
  }

  // Getters for all three

  // Setters for all three
}
```

Now when I do the following:

```
Tag tag = new Tag("Content");
tag.setAttr1("some_value");
tag.setAttr2("some_value");
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.processAnnoations(Tag.class);
System.out.println(xStream.toXML(tag));
```

I get the XML with an extra `<content>` tag. I don't want the extra `<content>` tag, I want it to be the content of `<Tag>`. How do I do that using XStream?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"content"})` Converter.

```
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"content"})
@XStreamAlias("Tag")
public class Tag {

  @XStreamAsAttribute
  String attr1;

  @XStreamAsAttribute
  String attr2;

  String content;

  public Tag(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tag tag = new Tag("Content");
      tag.attr1 = "some_value";
      tag.attr2 = "some_value";
      XStream xStream = new XStream();
      xStream.processAnnotations(Tag.class);
      System.out.println(xStream.toXML(tag));
  }
}
```